# Add array of array inside the array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get an item of array from other array and put it in the main array Have two arrays:

```
$original = array( 
            array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' ) , 
            array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' ), 
            array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' ), 
            array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' ) , 
            array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' )  
    );
$inserted = array( 'keyA' => 'valueA', 'keyB' => 'valueB' );
```

`$original` returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

But I want to insert `$inserted` in a specific position, for example, 3. I tried:

```
array_splice( $original, 3, 0, $inserted );
```

And now returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [3] => valueA
    [4] => valueB
    [5] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

How to put `$inserted` as a new item of array correctly? I not figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm not sure if array_splice is the better option. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
array_splice( $original, 3, 0, $inserted );
```

Do

```
array_splice( $original, 3, 0, array($inserted) );
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [key3] => value3
            [key4] => value4
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [key5] => value5
            [key6] => value6
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [keyA] => valueA
            [keyB] => valueB
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [key7] => value7
            [key8] => value8
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [key9] => value9
            [key10] => value10
        )
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!